# VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_RSRC_NFOUND (-1073807343): Insufficient location information or the requested device or resource is not present in the system

Tags: pyvisa

I am running a code to connect Keithley multimeter to my laptop. I am using windows 10 and python 2.7. But when I try to run the code, this appears. Help me, i am very basic in programming and computer and I am in need of help. I have been searching for solution for days but to no avail , after I have fixed one error, another error pops up. this is the latest error. I hope after this one is solved i can use it . This is the message from iPython

> runfile('C:/Users/user/Downloads/program (2).py',
>   wdir='C:/Users/user/Downloads') initializing Traceback (most recent
>   call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/user/Downloads/program (2).py', wdir='C:/Users/user/Downloads')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 710, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 86, in execfile
>       exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
>
> File "C:/Users/user/Downloads/program (2).py", line 422, in 
>       dmm = DMM()
>
> File "C:/Users/user/Downloads/program (2).py", line 40, in **init**
>       self.A=self.rm.open_resource('ASRL3::INSTR')
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\pyvisa\highlevel.py", line 1656,
>   in open_resource
>       res.open(access_mode, open_timeout)
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\pyvisa\resources\resource.py",
>   line 209, in open
>       self.session, status = self._resource_manager.open_bare_resource(self._resource_name,
>   access_mode, open_timeout)
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\pyvisa\highlevel.py", line 1613,
>   in open_bare_resource
>       return self.visalib.open(self.session, resource_name, access_mode, open_timeout)
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\pyvisa\ctwrapper\functions.py",
>   line 1213, in open
>       ret = library.viOpen(session, resource_name, access_mode, open_timeout, byref(out_session))
>
> File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\pyvisa\ctwrapper\highlevel.py",
>   line 188, in _return_handler
>       raise errors.VisaIOError(ret_value)
>
> VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_RSRC_NFOUND (-1073807343): Insufficient location
>   information or the requested device or resource is not present in the
>   system.